# ERRO: this - cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android

erro aparece na parte do código onde tenho "this"

```
private void sendEmail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this,email,subject,message);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
}
```

minha classe SendMail é essa

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    //Declaring Variables

    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;



    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A classe SendMail não tem nenhum construtor com essa assinatura: `SendMail(Activity, String, String, String)`

Comment: Então os construtores podem ser gerados automático, porém recebo erros no método Message

Comment: Pode explicar o que seriam construtores gerados automaticamente?

Comment: Pois parece ser erro de sintaxe mesmo, como há [alguns](http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-netbeans-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types/92540/8) [exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250436/android-java-view-cannot-be-applied-to).

Answer (score 2):

Na linha:

```
SendMail sm = new SendMail(this,email,subject,message);
```

Você está tentando chamar um construtor que não existe. Você deve criar um que aceite os mesmos parâmetros que estão sendo passados:

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    //Declaring Variables

    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message) {
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }

    ...
```